# Website monitor getting RecursionError after 100 calls

Tags: python, function, loops

```
s = requests.Session()

def login(userName,passWord):
    data = {
        'loginID': userName,
        'password': passWord,
        'btnallgo': 'SUBMIT',
        }
    print(f'[{datetime.now()}] | Posting Login => [asp]')
    response = s.post('http://bcps.browardschools.com/virtualcounselor/bsvc/loginstudent.asp', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)

login('#yourusername','#yourpassword')

def monitor():
    params = {
        'markper': '1',
        }
    print(f'[{datetime.now()}] | Checking Content => [get/asp]')
    response = s.get('https://bcps.browardschools.com/VirtualCounselor/bsvc/studentsched.asp', params=params, headers=headers)
    print(f'[{datetime.now()}] | Page Response => [{response.content}]')
    if response.content == (b'<P align=center><font color=red size=3><b>Your class schedule is currently unavailable.<br><br><br> Thank You</b></P>'):
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] | Schedule unavailable, retrying')
        time.sleep(2.4)
        monitor()
        
    elif response.content == (b'\r\n\r\n\r\n<HTML>\r\n<HEAD>\r\n<TITLE>APPLICATION TIMEOUT</TITLE></HEAD>\r\n<BODY BGCOLOR=WHITE LINK=RED ALINK=RED VLINK=RED>\r\n<P ALIGN=CENTER><BR><BR><FONT COLOR=RED SIZE=5>- APPLICATION HAS TIMED OUT -</FONT><BR><BR>FOR SECURITY MEASURES YOUR SESSION HAS TIMED OUT<BR>AFTER 15 MINUTES OF INACTIVITY OR WHEN YOU LOGGED OFF.<BR>PLEASE <A HREF="https://bcps.browardschools.com/virtualcounselor" TARGET="_parent">CLICK HERE</A> TO RELOGIN.</P>\r\n</BODY>\r\n</HTML> \r\n\r\n'):
        print(f'Generating new session{response.status_code}')
        login()
    
    else:
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] | Page Updated => {response.content}')
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='#yourwebhookhere')
        embed = DiscordEmbed(title='Page Update', description=f'{response.text}', color='03b2f8')
        embed.set_timestamp()
        webhook.add_embed(embed)
        response = webhook.execute()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(f'Sent webhook[status:{response.status_code}]')
        else:
            print(f'Error sending webhook[status:{response.status_code}]')
        
refresh = monitor()
```

I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

My code works to login/monitor a website and loop through the function if it hasn't found any changes. I understand there is a max (1000) function call limit but is there a way to re run the code if this issue is faced or make it so it can run infinitely without facing this issue?

Comment: If the class schedule is not available, the function calls itself endlessly, causing the error.

Comment: Well it's gonna delay (time.sleep) then send another request.. hence monitor

Comment: Can you explain @Firelord how to run that? im confused

Comment: Why does `monitor()` call `monitor()`? If you want something to happen more than once, recursion is generally the last option you want to try, when you're absolutely sure it's the best option. Here, it's problematic and there's no advantage.

Comment: if i made it another function would it have an issue? I'm confused